# Image is not loading properly

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking

I am displaying user's image as an profile picture. In another view controller there is a function through user can change profile picture and then it is stored to server side. But I have one problem that after sending image to server when I go to first page it shows me an old image not new one. When I directly open server url in browser it shows me new one. I think it is being cached somewhere. Here is my code of displaying image.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
NSString *urlString=[ImageURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"profile-picture"]];

NSURL *imgUrl=nil;
imgUrl=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
[imgProfile_serviceProvider setImageWithURL:imgUrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"No_image"]];
imgProfile_serviceProvider.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
imgProfile_serviceProvider.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imgProfile_serviceProvider.layer.borderWidth=0.5;

}
```

I am using UIImageView+AFnetworking.h to load image.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean cache of images for AFNetworking via following command:

```
[[AFImageCache sharedImageCache] removeAllObjects];
```

Also I think it will not refresh your image, you need to manually reset image url. Try to move your code to `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` to achieve this effect.

Comment: buit I have a button through you can go to first page. And each and every time whenever user will click on it I am intializing that class agian So each and evry time viewdidload will call.

Comment: In that case, you just need to clean cache=)

Comment: but this line is giving me an error .... AFImageCache not declared. I have not used whole library of AFNetworking

Comment: @vivek It's declared in UIImageView category of AFNetworking. `#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.m"` should resolve name